# MySQL - reference dynamic column in second dynamic column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
user | test_score
  a  |  50
  b  |  60
```

And I need query results that has a column for 1.5 times the test score and then the difference of that from the original. The results would be:

```
user | test_score | adjusted_test_score | test_score_diff
  a  |  50        |            75       |   25
  b  |  60        |            90       |   30
```

The query I tried:

```
 SELECT
 user AS user,
 test_score AS test_score,
 (test_score * 1.5) AS adjusted_test_score,
 (adjusted_test_score - test_score) AS test_score_diff
```

Returns an error that 'adjusted_test_score' column does not exist.

Is there a way to reference this column without doing a join?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT user, test_score, adjusted_test_score,
    (adjusted_test_score - test_score) AS test_score_diff
FROM (
    SELECT user, test_score, (test_score * 1.5) AS adjusted_test_score
    FROM source_table
)
```

Or you can also do this:

```
SELECT user, test_score, (test_score * 1.5) AS adjusted_test_score,
    ((test_score * 1.5) - test_score) AS test_score_diff
FROM source_table
```

Comment: I was using that second method as a workaround. The first method is what I hadn't thought of. It seems odd that you can't reference column aliases in the way I tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just repeat yourself?

SELECT
 user AS user,
 test_score AS test_score,
 (test_score * 1.5) AS adjusted_test_score,
 ((test_score * 1.5) - test_score) AS test_score_diff